# How to annotate web service parameters with constraints in java?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a GUI application that creates a bunch of `XML` documents using `jdom` and these documents conform to their respective schemas. It also has a `WSDL` creator class (which follows the standard schema provided by W3C) that creates a `Services.wsdl`. In this `WSDL` there are 'n' number of service descriptions with their respective entities(port, binding, type and message elements). The parameters of these web services have specific constraints associated with them.

**Question 1:** How to annotate service parameters with their specific constraints in the WSDL?

**Question 2:** Should I be using a custom SLAParameter extended from the WSLA Language by IBM or the WS-Policy language to annotate these parameters with their associated constraints?

**XML:**

```
<wsdl:message name="request">
        <part name="param1" type="xsd:string"/>
        <part name="param2" type="xsd:int"/>
</wsdl:message name="response"/>

<wsdl:message name="response"/>  
...
<wsdl:operation name="myMethod" parameterOrder="param1, param2">
    <input name="input" message="request"/>
    <output name="output" message="response"/>
</wsdl:operation>
```

**Java:**

```
void myMethod(String param1, int param2) ...
```

P.S. The above snippet's [source](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rwbs_map.html). `WSLA` and `WS-Policy` both complement `WSDL` in their own ways.

Comment: Asciidoc and REST can do this using Spring Boot.  I'm not aware of a SOAP standard way.

Comment: @duffymo Can you please elaborate on that? It does sound good for my next project. However, right now I need to stick to the SOAP protocol.

Comment: Please research asciidoc, REST, and Spring Boot.  Google will elaborate much better than I can in a comment or answer on SO.